# What is the meaning of "@INSTALLED_AT@" in a bash file

Tags: bash

I have a bash scripts that contains the following lines:

```
MY_HOME="@INSTALLED_AT@"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="@INSTALLED_AT@/lib"
MY_BIN="@INSTALLED_AT@/bin"

export  MY_HOME
export  LD_LIBRARY_PATH

exec "$MY_BIN/my.bin" ${1+"$@"}
```

I am particulary confused by **@INSTALLED_AT@**. Specifically, what does

```
MY_HOME="@INSTALLED_AT@"
```

do?

Comment: Where did you get the script from, what does it do?

Comment: I am trying to understand software which I haven't written myself. One of the bash scripts contains the code you see above. 
I don't know what the script is supposed to do, hence I asked this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably a *stub file*. The syntax `@INSTALLED_AT@` means nothing to `bash`; it's just a string as another one.

In the package/source/Makefile there is probably another script (maybe a simple `sed`) which will edit this stub and substitute the `@INSTALLED_AT@` with the actual installation path, which can be different or user-selectable.

See:

```
(0)asus-romano:~% var="@INSTALLED_AT@/bin"
(0)asus-romano:~% echo $var
@INSTALLED_AT@/bin
(0)asus-romano:~% echo $var | sed s+@INSTALLED_AT@+/usr/local+g 
/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: I have suspected as much. That clears things up for me. Thanks!